# HTML 2 column theme, left side scrolled right side dynamic height

Tags: html, css, layout

currently I have got a 2 columned layout. The left side is at about 5000px height. The right side is filled dynamiclly and for example 1200px height.

Now I want the left side to have the same height as the right side. For example 1200px. And the left side should be scrolled.

```
Currently: http://jsfiddle.net/2CDwB/2/

How it should be: http://jsfiddle.net/2CDwB/1/
```

But the problem is, the content of the right side is dynamic. So it isn't possible to use set heights like 1000px.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use overflow: hidden; in left side div.

```
   .left {
        float: left;
        height: 1200px;
        width: 20%;
        background: #f00;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: overflow: hidden isn't working.

I adjusted the example to show how it is looking at the moment:

    Link http://jsfiddle.net/2CDwB/2/

So there are no heights set. And I want to have the left side as high as the right side and scrollable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://BenDrums.com/stackoverflow/jxt_dfhhzksplb7.html

```
<div class="right">
<div class="left">
left side </br>....
</div> 
right side </br>
</div>


.left {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background: #f00;
    overflow: auto;
    display:block;
    height: 100%;
}

.right {
    float: left;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0f0;

}
```